# Querying Mysql in node js

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I just don't get this to work! some ideas?

I don't know what to do with the line 57 (const row of existing) {

Thanks if you can help :)

The error I get from this is

> ```
> Connected!
> Database created
> (node:8692) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: existing is not iterable
>     at insertUpdate (C:\Users\sondr\Desktop\koder\Ip_søk_syslog\app.js:57:23)
>     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
> (node:8692) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
> (node:8692) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
> Using syslog
> Tabel syslog_data created
> ^C
> C:\Users\sondr\Desktop\koder\Ip_søk_syslog>
> ```

```
async function insertUpdate() {
    // hent alle IPer listet i databasen
    const existing = await con.query(`SELECT ip, count FROM syslog_data`);
    // gå gjennom IP etter IP
    for (const key in tracker) {
        let exists = false;
        // gå gjennom eksisterende IPer fra databasen for hver gang (finnes bedre løsninger enn loop)
        for (const row of existing) {
            // sjekk om IP matcher IP som skal legges til/oppdateres, og legg til eller øk "count"
            if (row.ip !== key) continue;
            con.query(`UPDATE syslog_data SET count=${++row.count} WHERE ip="${row.ip}"`);
            exists = true;
            break;
        }
        // hopp til neste IP hvis den gjeldende eksisterer
        if (exists) continue;
        // legg til IP i databasen, og sett "count" verdien
        await con.query(`INSERT INTO syslog_data (ip, count) VALUES ("${key}", "${tracker[key]}")`);
    }
}

insertUpdate();


});
}
});
```

Comment: looks like `existing` is not iterable. can you please `console.log(existing)` right before the for loop?

Comment: The error message seems pretty straightforward : `existing is not iterable`. It means that your variable called `existing` is not an array and therefore, Node can't `for (const row of existing)` and crashes. Did you try to `console.log(existing)` and see what it outputs? Also, you have a bunch of extra `}); } });`

Comment: Enclose your `await` asynchronous blocks in `try/catch` blocks

Comment: I think line 57 should be ```for (const row in existing) {```

Comment: @wasanga7... but `existing` will still not be iterable, so this won't fix anything. And `row of existing` is perfectly correct, syntaxically. It iterates the _elements_ of an array directly, whereas `in` iterates the _indexes_ of each element.

Comment: console.log(existing) is not outputing anyting

Comment: Which libraries and versions are you using? Can you edit your question and show us your package.json? Make sure your answer isn't in here if this is the library https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql#getting-the-id-of-an-inserted-row If your answer is in there, please add an answer and accept it

Comment: @abelito https://uc8e0ec5a230bdbabba23dd317e5.dl.dropboxusercontent.com/cd/0/inline/AhsOaji9fuR3GMWQ5be7OMeWLRuyvidpPl4TYN5F4869h_OV7EGKMHvaJn-GSClfaetSk-10v0UbkGewFZdk7tBsrtWEuqgJkS5DZ4vRK2FnNw/file#

Comment: @Pomdre if it does not log anything, it should mean your previous query has failed

Comment: @GrafiCodeStudio The logged set just cosnol.log (); in the wrong place

Comment: https://uc8b8cccaec7b0492b697c72b651.dl.dropboxusercontent.com/cd/0/inline/AhuCVMG4ZlZYIX-8D5q4hH03e1i3WnAe7EzVPa_1q2Qs4YSsQ9Dv4skYcxNlHH2kLJqoexsPZGjfMXRcRQ2bzwOZasYtNQ8A1F_VJpDLRqPlBw/file#